# Pandas Converting NULL Int64 to Float64

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, parquet, pyarrow

I have a parquet with several nullable Int64 columns. When I read the parquet table in, convert to pandas, then convert back to parquet, those Int64 columns become Float64 (i'm assuming *because* they are nullable).

```
pq_table = self.pq.read_table('path/to/file.parquet')
df = pq_table.to_pandas()
new_pq_table = self.pa.Table.from_pandas(df)
```

I don't want to cast Int64 to Float64, so I tried specifying the schema-

```
pq_table = self.pq.read_table('path/to/file.parquet')
df = pq_table.to_pandas()
new_pq_table = self.pa.Table.from_pandas(df, schema=pq_table.schema)
```

Resulting in the following error-

> ArrowInvalid('Floating point value truncated', 'Conversion failed for column notification_id with type float64')

I believe this is happening at `to_pandas`.

How can I tell pandas to not convert fields?

Comment: the problem is that pandas uses `np.nan` to store nulls for numeric data, but this is of type float (just try `type(np.nan)`). AFAIK pandas does not support integer columns with nulls, but maybe you can somehow work around this when storing the data.

Comment: Could you ask about this on the mailing list or JIRA? Thanks

Comment: The mailing list is confusing me. Is it supposed to be like a forum where I create a thread by sending a topic?

Comment: Any news on this issue? I'm still experiencing this problem. Is there a solution/workaround?

Comment: @NirHedvat The workaround for me was to not load the pyarrow table into pandas. While the data stays in pyarrow, nullable ints are supported, but obviously cannot be manipulated outside of repartitioning (which is what we were trying to do). However, since writing this question I think a new version of pandas does allow nullable ints. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24/whatsnew/v0.24.0.html#optional-integer-na-support.

Let me know if that works for you. I'm curious

Comment: I'm already using Pandas 0.24. Error still occurs. I find it hard to believe they haven't fixed it yet. Don't they consider it as a bug?

Comment: It was considered a design choice. The reason why nullable ints are a bit more complicated is because ints are simple data types and with simple data types "null" doesn't exist. A null char with its byte value of 0x00 works because it was decided 0x00 is null. The same value for int (0x00) is just 0. Null ints are converted to floats because it's a structure that allows NaNs. To provide nullable ints, a Null Mask needs to be provided with the data- which they didn't implement. More information here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24/user_guide/missing_data.html#missing-data